# Meaning of $\gamma^\pm$ in Parton Fragmentation Functions

Tags: dirac-matrices, partons, hadronization

I was just working through the paper [*Parton fragmentation functions*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.02521) and came across equation 12.

What do $\gamma^{+}$ and $\gamma^{-}$ mean? The text doesn't explain this at all.

[image]

Comment: They define their $\pm$ notation for a general 4-vector on page 7.

Comment: That's true, but gamma is a matrix, not a 4-vector? That's why I'm so confused. Or is this specific gamma not related to the Dirac matrices? But then what's its meaning?

Comment: I think what they mean by four vector is to be applied to any object carrying a lorentz index, it would certainly explain the notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just agreed with a colleague that they most likely mean:

$\gamma^{\pm}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\gamma^{0}\pm\gamma^{3})$

as suggested for 4-vectors.